# How to derive specific heat of a crystalline material from phonon density of states?

Tags: phonons, vibrations, thermodynamics, phonon-density-of-state, lattice-thermal-conductivity

I have done a simulation of a crystalline material using DFT and have extracted its normal modes and its phonon density of states.

Does anyone have an algorithm/code or a detailed resource that can extract a crystalline material's specific heat or heat capacity form the phonon density of states ? What are other thermal properties that I can extract from the phonon-DOS ?

Comment: You could investigate almaBTE (https://almabte.bitbucket.io/) and see whether it can take your calculation as input.

Comment: Hi Elie, was Phil's comment helpful? Have you figured out an answer to this question now?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments.

Comment: I have indeed not figured out an answer for this, but I did not search thoroughly. Sorry for abandoning the question. Might answer it myself next week.

Comment: The almaBTE webpage seems to be dead for the last couple of months. But one can download the latest version from [the web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200925111046/https://almabte.bitbucket.io/downloads/almabte-v1.3.2.tar.gz) (tar.gz file - 179 MB) and visit the archived documentation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220125224326/https://almabte.bitbucket.io/docs/)